# jQuery Cycle - Align images with different dimensions on the right?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, jquery-cycle

I have a slideshow (jquery cycle) that I use for the background of a site. Problem is that I want to align the photos on the right and they have different dimmensions and for some reason the ones who have the smallest widths don't get aligned to the right... I tried to put the img's into divs like on person on the internet suggested and different things but to no avail. Is this possible without editing the plugin?

**HTML**:

```
<p class="slideshow">
   <img src="31.jpg" alt="" />
   <img src="35.jpg" alt="" />
   <img src="36.jpg" alt="" />
</p>
```

**CSS**:

```
p.slideshow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-999;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url(images/stripe-bg.png) repeat;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

    /* without setting the width and height 100% I get the
       annoying scroll bar on the right if photos are big in height */
    /*height:100%;
    width:100%;*/
}
```

Do you have any clues how to align all of them to the right?

**Thank you**,
Cris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also came across this problem, when I was trying to right-align some content within a container. This solution worked for us:

```
$('#sltitles span').each(function() {
  $(this).css({right: '0'});
});
```

You need to run it before the main plugin for it to apply to all content it seems. We ended up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sltitles span').each(function() {
      $(this).css({right: '0'});
    });
    $('#sltitles').cycle({
      fx: 'fade'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Maybe this will help someone else having the same problem.

Comment: This is a cool solution. Thanks! If I wanted to vertically align slideshow images with different dimensions, I would use the same solution only with "margin:0 auto", right?

Comment: Why add extra jquery to be processed client-side when you can just do it with css?

Answer (score 1):

Cycle plugin uses position absolute for the images, also `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`, so you will have to edit the plugin code, because is not part of the options of th eplugin.

Just open the plugin file and search for `left:0` and change it to `right:0`.

You will just have to do it again if you update the plugin.

Comment: Don't hack the cycle plugin, there are better ways that will easily withstand upgrading the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple straight-up css solution that doesn't involve hacking the plugin or a lot of bloated extra jQuery code.

```
p.slideshow img {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}
```

This will also work well for non-image slide items:

```
div.cycle-slide {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try floating the images within a div :

```
<div class="slideshow">
 <img src="31.jpg" alt="" />
 <img src="35.jpg" alt="" />
 <img src="36.jpg" alt="" />
</div>


div.slideshow {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
z-index:-999;
overflow:hidden;
background: url(images/stripe-bg.png) repeat;
margin:0;
padding:0;

/* width:;
height:;*/ }



 div.slideshow img { float:right: display:inline}
```

Comment: Floating the images doesn't work with Cycle since the images are absolutely positioned by the plugin.